# Load .pem with public key into x509Certificate2

Tags: .net-core, pem, x509certificate2

*Notice: I'm a cryptography n00b, so please take that into account.*

I have a ***.net core 3.1 console app*** where I need to ***load a public key certificate from a `.pem` file into `x509Certificate2`***.

The test file I'm using is this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And the code loading it:

```
public static string GetPublicKeyXml(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

        var file = new FileInfo(path);
        if (!file.Exists)
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"{path} neexistuje!");

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(file.FullName);
        .....
    }
```

But when I try to load the file I get:

```
{"Požadovaný objekt nebyl nalezen."} Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException
```

Which translated into english is:

```
Required object not found
```

and stack trace:

```
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName)
at XXXXXXXXXXXX.Decryptor.GetPublicKeyXml(String path) in XXXXXXXXXXXXX\Decryptor.cs:line 43
```

**How to load the file into x509Certificate2?**

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Public key is just a part of certificate. You need whole X509 certificate to load it. It will probably have this header `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: It should be possible, how else would you give someone your public key so that they can encrypt the data for you to decrypt? I'll look into the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: Public key is not certificate. It is a part of public certificate, but not same thing. This is why your code fails.

Comment: Ok. I will write more complex question and try to solve my problems with the program. Thanks.